# How can I concatenate these two DFA's?

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let the alphabet = {a, b} for $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$

$L_{1}$ = { w | w contains an even number of a's }

$L_{2}$ = {w | w has at least 1 b after each a }

$\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}$

## $\hspace{4cm}L_{1}$

[image]

$\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}$

## $\hspace{4cm}L_{2}$

[image]
$\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}$

How can I find the concatenation of $L_{1}$.$L_{2}$ represented as a DFA?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two new arrows starting in the final state of the first automaton simulating what happens in the initial state of the second automaton.[image]

I think it would be like this. You can then determinise this automaton. I am sorry it is handwritten.

Comment: Is that a valid DFA? With A(a) -> B and A(a) -> D? Wouldn't that make it Non-deterministic?

Comment: @Tristen You are right, it is not deterministic. But you can determinise it, since every automaton is equivalent to a deterministic one